# Passing ArrayList<Subclass> to method declared with List<Superclass>

Tags: java, generics

I have a method with a parameter containing generics.

```
public static void readList(List<ModelObject> list)
{
    // more code
}
```

I want to pass an `ArrayList` of `ModelObjectImplementation`s to this method.

```
ArrayList<ModelObjectImplementation> myList;
myList = ...

readList(myList); // gives compilation error
```

`ModelObject` is an interface that `ModelObjectImplementation` implements. How can I change the method declaration to allow this?

Comment: Add a cast to `List<ModelObject>` before passing the object. Also, your array should be `ArrayList<? extends ModelObject>`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use wildcards, if you're using Java version 1.5 and higher.

```
public static void readList(List<? extends ModelObject> list)
```

This solution is more generic, because it fits for all `java.util.List` interface implementations and subclasses/subinterfaces of `ModelObject`.
For more details go to wildcards [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Comment: Generics were also introduced in 1.5, so I think it's safe to assume he's using that.