# Method to accept both List of interfaces or list of implementations

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have an interface and several implementations. I would like to create a method which can accept both a collection of interfaces and collection of any of its implementations.

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public interface ITest {
    }

    public static class Test1 implements ITest {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ITest t1 = new Test1();
        List<ITest> lt1  = ImmutableList.of(t1);
        Test1 t2 = new Test1();
        List<Test1> lt2  = ImmutableList.of(t2);
        buildIntRange(lt1);
        buildIntRange(lt2);
    }

    private static List<ITest> method(List<ITest> test) {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(test);
    }
}
```

Is it possible for the method to accept both `List<ITest>` and `List<Test1>` as its argument?

Comment: "*possible for the method to accept both List and List as its argument*" - What? Is this a typo? And should `method` be `buildIntRange`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing ArrayList<Subclass> to method declared with List<Superclass>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643443/passing-arraylistsubclass-to-method-declared-with-listsuperclass)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just modify the signature to accept a `List<? extends ITest>`:

```
private static List<ITest> method(List<? extends ITest> test) {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(test);
}
```

Comment: A type variable might make this nicer: `<T extends ITest> List<T> method(List<? extends T> test)`. Just a bit more flexible in what you can use the output for, as in you can use it to produce a `List<ITest>` and a `List<Test1>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your method generic, like so:

```
public static <T extends ITest> List<T> method(List<T> test)
```

Comment: I think the wildcard solution is a little more clear seeing as we don't actually care about `T`. Although you might want to return the same type of list that you pass in. Upvotes for both

Comment: The proposal by Joe C, namely

public static <T extends ITest> List<T> method(List<T> test)

resolves an issue where the caller is passing a list of some other class (a class which implements ITest), avoids compiler warning that the other proposal:

List<? extends ITest>

gives compiler warning.