# How do I call a method that has Interface parameters?

Tags: java, interface

I have an interface `VersionInterface` which is implemented by my object `ObjectDefinition`

I also have a method that accepts two `List<VersionInterface>` as arguments.

Since `ObjectDefinition` implements `VersionInterface`, why can't I pass my two `List<VersionInterface>`as arguments to my method?

**Method Definition:**

```
public List<VersionInterface> updateArtifact(List<VersionInterface> currentCopy, List<VersionInterface> updatedCopy)
```

**`ObjectDefinition` Definition:**

```
public class ObjectDefinition implements VersionInterface {
```

**How I'm calling `updateArtifact`:**

```
service.updateArtifact(currentCopy, updatedCopy);
```

`currentCopy` and `updatedCopy` are both `ArrayList<ObjectDefinition>`

I get:

> `The method updateArtifact(List<VersionInterface>, List<VersionInterface>) in the type ORService is not applicable for the arguments (List<ObjectDefinition>, List<ObjectDefinition>)`

**Edit:** 
My problem has to do with interfaces and not subclasses

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643443/passing-arraylistsubclass-to-method-declared-with-listsuperclass) existing post answers the question.

Comment: my example uses interfaces and does not deal with extending

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that because the method prototype specifies that it's returning a List of VersionInterface objects, not a List of ObjectDefinition objects.

VersionInterface is an Interface, as you've demonstrated. Maybe ObjectDefinition is the only class that implements that interface, but in general that is not the case in Java. There could be multiple implementations of VersionInterface, and the List that is returned may contain objects of various different types.